# How to replace Unicode Character in Notepad++

Tags: find-and-replace

I have got a .xlf files that looks like the picture below:

[image]

I wonder how do I search and replace unicode character **"xE5"** to **"æ"** 
I thought I could search for:**^0145 =xE5** and replace **"æ"**, that did not work.

If this is not possible I could use another text editor (example ultraedit).

here is the pasted text from the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 xliff-core-1.2-strict.xsd">
  <file xmlns:bind="http://bind.sorona.se" original="CTO12623_1_en-GB-da.xml" source-language="en" datatype="xml" date="2015-11-11T15:35:51Z" target-language="da" product-name="Anders_LP8504_151111" bind:file-id="78452" bind:file-hash="85075c54359fa47b087d6c67ec967f43">
    <header>
      <tool tool-name="Sorona TMS" tool-id="bind" tool-version="3.1.5" tool-company="Sorona Innovation" />
      <count-group name="word-count">
        <count count-type="total" unit="word">2743</count>
      </count-group>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="e1ca41ef868a74944745b8cd1dfa59e7" translate="yes" approved="no" restype="string" resname="p">
        <source>The trench compactor LP 8504 is a radio controlled trench compactor. It has a robust design and is suitable for compaction of medium to deep layers of cohesive and granular soils on limited areas such as trenches, construction back-fills and on roads. No other use is permitted.</source><seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">The trench compactor LP 8504 is a radio controlled trench compactor. It has a robust design and is suitable for compaction of medium to deep layers of cohesive and granular soils on limited areas such as trenches, construction back-fills and on roads. No other use is permitted.</mrk></seg-source>
        <target state="translated"><mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">Vibrationstromlen LP 8504 er radiostyret. Den har et robust design og er beregnet til komprimering af middel til dybe lag af sammenh篧ende og granuleret jord p塢egr篳ede omr楥r s塳om grr, anl稳opfyldninger og p塶eje. Den m塩kke anvendes til andre form欮</mrk></target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="3b3dbf229f5f1f06ab9427d689c9740b" translate="yes" approved="no" restype="string" resname="p">
        <source>The LP trench compactor must only be used in well-ventilated areas, as is the case for all combustion engine machines.</source><seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">The LP trench compactor must only be used in well-ventilated areas, as is the case for all combustion engine machines.</mrk></seg-source>
        <target state="translated"><mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">LP vibrationstromlen m塬ige som alle andre maskiner med forbr篤ingsmotorer kun bruges i godt ventilerede omr楥r.</mrk></target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="3ceced74b90bcbc582c1857395a8abf1" translate="yes" approved="no" restype="string" resname="p">
        <source>The LP trench compactor must not be towed behind vehicles.</source><seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">The LP trench compactor must not be towed behind vehicles.</mrk></seg-source>
        <target state="translated"><mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">LP vibrationstromlen m塩kke sl磥s efter biler.</mrk></target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="c1ff7c8ab3ea4123fc2d5fb6a105d98b" translate="yes" approved="no" restype="string" resname="p">
        <source>Handbrake</source><seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">Handbrake</mrk></seg-source>
        <target state="translated"><mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">H毤bremse</mrk></target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

I have also attached the xlf file here is a link:
[Here is link to download the xlf](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=27625404422603135179)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] and add a sample of the text we can copy and work with.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did Post the code also attached the file.
so its your choice what fit your requirements best:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I wonder how do I search and replace unicode character `xE5`" with `æ`

Note that `æ` is actually Unicode `00E6` not `00E5`.

Search and replace is not the right way to get the correct characters displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The above states the encoding is `utf-8` but the file is actually encoded as `ANSI`.

You need to convert the file correctly to `UTF-8`, as follows:

1. Open *Testfile.xlf*
2. File looks like:

   > [image]

   Unicode is incorrectly displayed.
3. Menu > *Encoding* > Select *Encode in ANSI*

   > [image]
4. File looks like:

   > [image]

   Unicode is correctly displayed.
5. Select all file contents (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)
6. Menu > *Encoding* > Select *Convert to UTF-8*

   > [image]
7. Save the File (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
8. Close and reopen.
9. File is now correctly encoded as UTF-8 and Unicode characters display correctly.

---

#### How can you see the file is actually ANSI?

The cygwin `file` utility shows this (before and after conversion):

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ file -i Testfile*.xlf
Testfile.xlf:          application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1
TestfileConverted.xlf: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Perfect answer! one of the better answears many thanks!

Comment: How can you see the file is actually ANSI? 
and I understand the declaration says:encoding-utf-8.

Comment: I used the cygwin `file` utility. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Answer updated. Scroll to the end.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove UTF-8/unicode chars entirely, click `Encoding` in NPP and do the following steps, in order:

1. Select **Encode in UTF-8** (if it's currently in ANSI)
2. Select **Convert to ANSI** (also under encoding)
3. Save file

When I do that, all the UTF-8/unicode chars go away.